# Is it safe to completely ignore variadic arguments to a C function?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I'm have a function that roughly looks like so:

```
typedef struct SomeType {
  ...
} SomeType;

void TakesArgs(SomeType *t1, ...) {
     // iterates through arguments
}

// usage:
TakesArgs(&a, &b, &c);
```

Do I run any strange risks with memory (or otherwise) if I were to change `TakesArgs` to a no-op, while still leaving all calling code unchanged?

```
void TakesArgs(SomeType *t1, ...) {
    return;
}

// usage unchanged: 
TakesArgs(&a, &b, &c);
```

In other words, will skipping the `va_list`/`va_start` dance that was executed in the original implementation have any strange side effects?

Comment: Variadic functions are not part of memory management.

Comment: This is perfectly safe. I don't feel comfortable turning that into an answer because I can't rigorously back it up, but it's definitely safe.

Comment: I don't think there will be strange side effects, as the compiler will most generate code that reserves some space on the stack for &a, &b, and &c, and then pop them off afterwards, just like a normal function call (regardless of the number of arguments passed). However, I'm not entirely sure about this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly safe. You are not required to read all variadic arguments just for the sake of reading them. You are not required to even start the variadic argument reading sequence inside `TakesArgs`.

Under the hood it usually means that the burden of performing any argument-passing maintenance tasks is bestowed upon the calling code (they way it works in what is usually recognized as "traditional" C calling convention). The callee does not have to do anything.

Comment: @Olaf: What wording specifically?

Comment: ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.16.1.3 *`va_end`* ¶2 says: _The `va_end` macro facilitates a normal return from the function whose variable
argument list was referred to by the expansion of the `va_start` macro, or the function
containing the expansion of the `va_copy` macro, that initialized the `va_list ap`. The
`va_end` macro may modify `ap` so that it is no longer usable (without being reinitialized
by the `va_start` or `va_copy` macro). If there is no corresponding invocation of the
`va_start` or `va_copy` macro, or if the `va_end` macro is not invoked before the
return, the behavior is undefined._

Comment: The wording says "if there's a `va_start`, there must be a `va_end`", and "there mustn't be a `va_end` without a `va_start`", but it doesn't there must be a `va_start`.  The key word __corresponding__ means that if you call `va_end` before you call `va_start`, you have problems; it does not mean that you have to call `va_start` (but if you don't, you mustn't call `va_end` either).  (I'm skipping `va_copy` for convenience, but you can interpolate appropriately.)

Comment: @Olaf: This wording clearly refers to invocation of `va_end` without a previous invocation of `va_start`/`va_copy`. It is UB. It also refers to invocation of `va_start`/`va_copy` without a terminating `va_end`. It is also UB. But it does not say anything about not invoking `va_start` and `va_end` at all.

Answer (score 2):

[Edited in response to comments.]

There are systems where by default it is the callee's job to pop arguments.  That would obviously get you into trouble.  *But*, it's precisely for this reason that variadic functions have to be properly declared, and the declaration has to be properly visible to callers.  The reason is that on those systems, variadic functions have to use a non-default calling sequence where the caller pops the arguments, because only the caller can be sure how many there are.  So you should be safe as long as your functions are properly declared.

Comment: in `__stdcall`, it is the callee's job to clean up the stack.   That's not "back in the day", as `__stdcall` is still widely used.   In `cdecl`, the caller is responsible for cleaning the stack.

Comment: That was not weired, but e.g. standard for the Pascal-languages. IT was acutally for a good reason. Drawback was the callee had first to pop the return address. Unless the CPU has special return-and-deallocate instruction, e.g. as the 680xx Family. That died with RISC architectures rising.

Comment: @abelenky: I know that as `pdecl` as in `Pascal`. IIRC, gcc has some attributes for this.

Comment: @Olaf: The x86 also has instructions for that; `RET 12`, for instance, pops the return address off the stack as usual, then pops a further 12 bytes worth of arguments into the bit bucket.

Comment: @SamB: Interesting; they might have stolen that from the 68000 (`RTD` - return and deallocate) :-). But that actually was not the point.

Comment: Indeed, the [`__stdcall documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/stdcall?view=msvc-170) states that `__stdcall` is replaced by `__cdecl` for variadic function: *the callee cleans the stack, so the compiler makes vararg functions `__cdecl`.*

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's safe, though the standard isn't *quite* explicit on this point.

[N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 7.16 paragraph 3 says:

> If access to the varying arguments is desired, the called function
>   shall declare an object (generally referred to as **`ap`** in this
>   subclause) having type **`va_list`**.

Note the beginning of that sentence: "**If** access to the varying arguments is desired".  The implication is that if access to the varying arguments is not desired, there's no need to declare a `va_list` object -- which would make it impossible to invoke `va_start`, `va_arg`, or `va_end`.

A possible counterargument is that the description of `va_end` (N1570 7.16.1.3) says:

> If there is no corresponding invocation of the **`va_start`** or **`va_copy`**
>   macro, or if the **`va_end`** macro is not invoked before the return, the
>   behavior is undeﬁned.

However, given the context, I believe that applies if `va_end` is not invoked *after `va_start` is invoked*.

Comment: re 7.16.1.3, I believe that means "if you call `va_end` *without* having called `va_start` first".